# spring boot: add new yml files to application config

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i want developers to be able to locally override some configuration properties. (let's say we work on google drive and everyone should test it on its own account). 
i don't want to override properties using command line (because it has to be set inside every IDE configuration and on every CLI run).

what i want is: application should use all the standard spring boot config files (`application.yml` etc) and also look for e.g. `local.yml` (on the classpath) or some file inside `user.home`. and those additional files should override other settings.

how to add new `yml` resources and order them correctly?

edit: i know spring's default orders and locations. question is about adding **new** ones

Answer (score 6):

There's a new way to do this, after Spring Boot v2.4, by using `spring.config.import`: https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4#importing-additional-configuration

By adding this part to your `application.yml` file, you should be able to import the additional configuration:

```yaml
spring:
  config:
    import: local.yml
```

The article also has this section:

> Imports can be considered as additional documents inserted just below the document that declares them. They follow the same top-down ordering as regular multi-document files: An import will only be imported once, no matter how many times it is declared.

So the contents of `local.yml` should be handled as if they were appended to the end of `application.yml`, thereby allowing you to [override any property](https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4#document-order) in `application.yml`.

Answer (score 5):

If you look in the Spring Boot documentation about the locations for configuration files (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config), you can see, that they are loaded from the following places (amongst others):

- Profile-specific application properties outside of your packaged jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants)
- Application properties outside of your packaged jar (application.properties and YAML variants).

There are two default locations where they are loaded from ( see http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files):

- A /config subdirectory of the current directory.
- The current directory

Current directory in this case means the working directory for the Java process (Usually the directory where the JAR is located, or in case of running with in the IDE, usually the project root folder). So the developers just can place their own configuration files in that places and they are automatically loaded (and will override properties within the JARs). Add that files to .gitignore (or .svnignore or ...) and they won't accidentally committed into your repository.

Answer (score 0):

From [Spring Boot Documentation : Application property files](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files):

SpringApplication will load properties from application.properties files in the following locations and add them to the Spring Environment:

- A /config subdirectory of the current directory.
- The current directory
- A classpath /config package
- The classpath root

The list is ordered by precedence (properties defined in locations higher in the list override those defined in lower locations).

This also goes for yaml, so you everyone can add application.yml under `config` directory, under the directory you run the spring boot jar from.

You can also customize the extra configuration file to be `local.yml` if you'd like by using `spring.config.location`:

`--spring.config.location=classpath:/application.yml,classpath:/local.yml`

Note however:

> > spring.config.name and spring.config.location are used very early to determine which files have to be loaded so they have to be defined as an environment property (typically OS env, system property or command line argument).

Comment: @piotrek why not? Your argument that you can't use it within an IDE seems odd to me, because stuff like environment variables and properties like `spring.config.location` can be easily set within an IDE as well.

Comment: it's not that i "can't". i just "don't want to". it has to be set for every single runtime configuration, for every single command line invocation, by every developer. i want application to work without any additional options and it should pick up existing config files automatically

Answer (score 0):

To provide the configuration from external config file in spring-boot application -

```
-Dspring.config.location=file:/home/vfroot/Workspace/project/MODULE_HOME/application.yaml
```

this command can be run with terminal:

> mvn clean install -Dspring.config.location
>   = file:/home/vfroot/Workspace/MODULE_HOME/application.yaml

or need to set in Eclipse `VM argument`.

Also to set the active profiles :

```
 -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since i am new in Spring Boot & Restfull Web Services. However, i managed to add a new .yml file to mange database and server port.

Instructions that i followed:

1. Project File.
2. Other Sources
3. src/main/resources
4. default package
5. right click on "default package"
6. add new YAML FILE

Or of YAML File option not available
   5. right click on "default package"
   6. then in categories: other  -->  File Types: YAML File